# Neither dock or bar appears on external monitor when I move an app to it How can I fix it?

Tags: display, dock

This just started recently.  I have a MacBook Pro 15 2018 16 GB ram 512 GB HD. The external monitor is a Dell 24 inch with a 3820 x 2160 resolution.

I use it primarily for Azure development. 
If I position Safari against the top the monitor, the bar does not appear. It stays on main screen.

Comment: System prefs > Mission Control .. is 'Displays have separate Spaces' enabled? If it isn't, then your Spaces will move in 'pairs' & the menu & Dock will always remain on the primary display.

Comment: I tried that, but it did not fix the problem. I had turned off Mission Control because  I do not need or like it

Comment: I've no idea how you could 'turn off' Mission Control.

Answer (score 1):

I have a secondary monitor hooked up to my iMac, take a look at "System Preferences > Displays", does it match the screenshot I have attached?

You can move the blue rectangles (screens) by clicking and dragging to the desired position, the same applies to the "bar" at the top of the screen

Hope this helps
[image]

Comment: Yes it did. Thank you for the suggestion

Comment: Except now when I move a window back to the Mac screen, the bar and dock are still on the external monitor